# Expectation over a minimum

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X \geq 0$ a random variable.Using only the definition of the expectation (without using Fatou Lemma, BCT,MCT) show that : $$\lim_{t \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[X \wedge t] = \mathbb{E}[X],$$ where $t$ is a continous variable , i.e $t \in \mathbb{R}.$

**My effort**

Assume that $t > 0$ otherwise $X \wedge t = t$ which is trivial. Then $Y := X \wedge t$ is a nonnegative variable and we have

\begin{align*}
E[Y] &= \int_0^\infty P( Y > k) dt \\
       &= \int_0^\infty P( X > k, t > k) dt \\
       &= \int_0^\infty P( X > t)\mathbf{1}\{ t > k\} dt \\
       &= \int_0^t P(X > k)dt
\end{align*}

But does this closes the proof?

Comment: If you can't use MCT, just reproduce its proof...

Comment: without using MCT

Comment: That what I say : if you can't use it, just copy its proof...

Comment: no I want another way

Comment: Shouldn't your integrals be $dk$ rather than $dt$?

Comment: Modulo the $dk$/$dt$ correction, yes you are basically done now by the definition of an improper integral.

Comment: @jlammy can you write it as a complete answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$
You are basically there already, modulo some typos.
$$\mathbb E[X\wedge t] = \int_0^\infty\mathbb P(X\wedge t>k)\dd k =\int_0^t\mathbb P(X>k)\dd k.$$
Now
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbb E[X\wedge t]=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t\mathbb P(X>k)\dd k=\int_0^\infty\mathbb P(X>k)\dd k=\mathbb E[X].$$
The middle equality in the above line is just the definition of what it means for one of the limits of the integral to be $\infty$.